# QML WebView flash does not play

Tags: flash, webview, qml

I have not been able to get flash to play when running the following qml script with qmlviewer.

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import QtWebKit 1.0

WebView {
    id: webView
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    settings.pluginsEnabled: true
    url: "http://www.youtube.com"
}
```

I am using Qt 4.8.2 and this does not work on Windows 7 or my Debian Linux distro. When trying to play youtube flash content I get the message:

The Adobe Flash Player or an HTML5 supported browser is required for video playback.

I am able to play this content on IE 8 and in Chrome.  What plugin am I supposed to use that my WebView will recognize?  Isn't it supposed to share the same plugin that Chrome uses since they are both WebKit based?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. I've tested in on my systems (OpenSUSE Linux and Windows 7) and the Youtube flash player works just fine. I'm using Qt 4.8.7 and Qt 4.8.2, respectively. So there has to be problem with your flash plugin.

If you enable `settings.pluginsEnabled` the web view will use any [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)-style browser plugin installed on your system. Testing in Chrome or in Internet Explorer isn't helpful to check whether the Flash NPAPI plugin works because Google Chrome ships with its own bundled flash player and Internet Explorer uses a different API to load plugins. Try Firefox, that one will actually use the same plugin web view depends on.